# Implementing sessions and security in REST web apps?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

*Please Note:*

This is a long post.

Not sure if the title of the post is even suitable :(

Down-voters please provide some constructive feedback to improve this post before you take-off.

==========================================================

I am implementing a simple **REST API in Java** which exposes 3 services:

1. Allows clients to register their applications. **POST /register**

> Request:

```
{
"display_name" : "MyAwesomeApplication" 
}
```

> Response:

```
{
"application_id" : "abc123def123..." ,
"application_secret" : "abc123def123..." ,
"display_name" : "MyAwesomeApplication" 
}
```

2. Allows applications to authenticate before sending log messages. **POST /auth**

***This endpoint uses a simplified version of Basic Authentication***

> Header

```
Name                         Value
Authorization                application_id:application_secret
```

> Response

```
{
"access_token" : "c47026d9­90bf­4480­a259­a953bc103495" 
}
```

3. Sends log messages.  **POST /log**

> Header

```
Name                         Value
Authorization                access_token
```

> Request

```
{
"application_id" : "abc123def123..." ,
"logger" : "com.logger.service.Uploader" ,
"level" : "Error" ,
"message" : "The communication pipeline is broken." 
}
```

> Response:

```
{
"success" : true|false
}
```

So, far I have implemented these functional requirements successfully, but **I have no clue how to implement non-functional requirements like**:

**1.** The sensitive data must be encrypted.

**2.** Only one active session per application(user of my web service) is allowed.

**3.** The session lifetime must be configurable in the database.

**4.** All log requests must be handled asynchronously.

**5.** Log endpoint requires authentication through an access token.

**6.** Implement a rate-limiting request to avoid possible attacks, allowing only 60 requests per minute by application. If you use up your 60 api calls then you will receive “rate limit exceeded” message and must wait 5 minutes before can make requests again.

**Can someone please point me to some resources/tutorials targeted to these use cases?**

I have read practically everything I could get my hands on in SO and google and the more I am reading the more I am getting confused. May be instead of trying to learn these skills in terms of REST, I should just try to implement them in a very basic client-server web app, please suggest if this should be the case.

**This is my first REST web app, so please consider me a complete noob and guide accordingly.**

Comment: The best option is not to reinvent the wheel. Use Spring Security and Spring Session (which operate as servlet filters and don't require you to write your application in Spring).

Comment: @chrylis Yes, I noticed this in few SO posts but I will have to learn a new technology and I might not learn the basics. My intention here is to learn things old school way, even if it is a bit harder and then go on and learn sophisticated techniques like Spring security and Spring session as a next step.

Comment: Then why aren't you doing this in assembly language? "Old school" is old school precisely because there are better ways to spend your time than mucking around by hand with components that will break your application if you screw them up.

Comment: :) Yes, its a nice suggestion but I guess it will be too old school. Are you suggesting that it is not possible to implement my non-functional requirements without using spring in any easy way. I feel that Spring might be a little too much for a pretty simple Web service like this one.
Doesn't Jersey provide something out of the box with little coding effort from my side to implement this.

Comment: Of course you *can* do all that, but it's just not worth learning it. Look into Spring Boot, which is massively easier than building a "traditional" war application and handles lots of this for you magically.